# Adding element to array, random number outcome

Tags: c

I'm trying to be able to add a pic to the existing staff using this function:

```
Staff addpic(Staff array[], int staffCount)
{
    Staff newStaff = {};    

    printf("type in the name you would like to add pic to \n");
    fgets(newStaff.name, 30, stdin);

    for(int i = 0; i< staffCount; i++) {

        if(strcmp(array[i].name,newStaff.name)==0) {
            if(array[i].imagecount<5) {
                printf("type in pic\n");
                int newpic;
                scanf("%d",&newpic);

                array[i].imagecount++;
                int *newpics = realloc(newStaff.pic, (array->imagecount) * sizeof(int));
                newpics[array->imagecount-1] = newpic; 
                newStaff.pic = newpics;
            }
        } 
    }
    return newStaff;
}
```

but it does now work as I was hoping. it adds a new pic but just a random number.
the out come will look like this:

```
type in the name you would like to add pic to 
Anna
type in pic
99
1.Show existing  
2.add pic to a staff
1
Adam    1,2,3,
Anna    1,2,3,-455802818,
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should absolutely never ever use `gets()` because you can't stop the user from overflowing the input buffer. Replace it with `fgets(newStaff.name, 30, stdin);`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. Also indent your code properly.

Comment: Also, could you add the code where you call `addPic` to the question.

Comment: Why is `fgets(newStaff.name, 30, stdin);` there twice? Did you intend to enter data for another `struct` member which is still  uninitialised?

Comment: `scanf("%d",&newpic);` - does scanf return `1` ?

Answer (score 1):

The mistakes are:

- `array[i]` is updated, but `imagecount` of `array[0]` is used to select the element to be updated.
- `array[i].pic` is not updated while `array[i].imagecount` is updated. `newStaff.pic`, which is passed to `realloc()` and updated, is initialized to `NULL` and not related with `array[i].pic`.

Corrected verson:

```
Staff addpic(Staff array[], int staffCount)
{
    Staff newStaff = {};

    printf("type in the name you would like to add pic to \n");
    fgets(newStaff.name, 30, stdin);

    for(int i = 0; i< staffCount; i++) {

        if(strcmp(array[i].name,newStaff.name)==0) {
            if(array[i].imagecount<5) {
                printf("type in pic\n");
                int newpic;
                scanf("%d",&newpic);

                array[i].imagecount++;
                /* use array[i].pic instead of newStaff.pic and use array[i].imagecount instead of array->imagecount */
                int *newpics = realloc(array[i].pic, (array[i].imagecount) * sizeof(int));
                /* use array[i].imagecount instead of array->imagecount */
                newpics[array[i].imagecount-1] = newpic; 
                /* update array[i].pic instead of newStaff.pic */
                array[i].pic = newpics;
            }
        } 
    }
    return newStaff;
}
```

Comment: 1. Isn't the name too long? 2. Is the name correct? (`fgets()` save newline characters and the code that initialize `array` isn't disclosed) 3. Is `imagecount` of the specified element small enough?

Comment: Code to remove the newline character from `fgets()`: `char *lf; if ((lf = strchr(newStaff.name, '\n')) != NULL) *lf = '\0';`

Comment: Initialization part or using `realloc()` seems wrong. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: To use `realloc()`, allocate the buffer via `malloc()` or initialize it to `NULL` first.