# Adding element to array, old values turns to 0 but new shows

Tags: c

I have written this program where I can add pics to a staff using their names. but right now it adds the new value but the already existing values becomes 0.

this is the outcome:

```
type in the name you would like to add pic to 
Anna
type in pic
55
1.Show existing  
2.add pic to a staff
1
Adam    1,2,3,
Anna    0,0,0,55,
```

the rest of the code:

```
typedef struct Staff
{

 char  name[30];
 int   *pic;
 int   imagecount;
 } Staff;


void printStaff(Staff *pStaff)
{
printf("%s    ", pStaff->name);



  if ( pStaff->pic) {
  for(int i=0; i<pStaff->imagecount; i++){

 printf("%d,",pStaff->pic[i]); 
  }
  }

 printf("\n");
 }



void PrintList(Staff aLista[], int staffCount)
 {

for (int i = 0; i < staffCount; i++) {

   printStaff(&aLista[i]);
 }
}
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
Staff addpic(Staff array[], int staffCount)
{
Staff newStaff = {};    

printf("type in the name you would like to add pic to \n");
fgets(newStaff.name, 30, stdin);


for(int i = 0; i< staffCount; i++) {

    if(strcmp(array[i].name,newStaff.name)==0) {
        if(array[i].imagecount<5) {
            printf("type in pic\n");
            int newpic;
            scanf("%d",&newpic);

            array[i].imagecount++;
            int *newpics = realloc(newStaff.pic, (array[i].imagecount) * sizeof(int));
            newpics[array[i].imagecount-1] = newpic; 
            array[i].pic = newpics;

        }
    } 
}
return newStaff;
```

the rest of the code:

```
 int main(void)
 {
  int staffCount=0;



 int input;


 int test[3]  = {1,2,3};

 Staff myStaff[5] = { {"Adam", test, 3},{"Anna",test,3} };

 staffCount=2;

 do
 {
printf("1.Show existing  \n");

printf("2.add pic to a staff");
printf("\n");
scanf("%d", &input);

switch(input)
{

  case 1:
PrintList(myStaff,staffCount);

break;
  case 2: 
 addpic(myStaff,staffCount);
   break; 

        default: 
            printf("inccorect inpput\n");
            break; 
   }
   }while (input<'1' ||input<'2');


 return 0;
  }
```

any help is appreciated, but I'm new to coding so keep that in mind.

Comment: Have you copied the correct code for `addpic`? Do you really call `fgets` *twice* for the name?

Comment: And what do you mean by "does not work as it should"? How *should* it work? How *does* it work? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: Lastly a possible hint: The "array" you pass in to `addpic`, is it initialized in any way before you call `addpic`?

Comment: This `Staff newStaff = {};` is not a valid C initializer. Are you perhaps compiling as C++ (I believe it's valid in that language) or using specific compiler extensions?

Comment: Haven't you asked nearly the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54999925/adding-element-to-array-random-number-outcome) before?

Comment: There are many issues. One of them is mixing `scanf` and `fgets`, don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

In the `addpic` function you do

```
int *newpics = realloc(array[i].pic, ...);
```

One problem is that if you do it for one of the two elements you have initialized in `array`, then `array[i].pic` is pointing to the first element of an *array* (the array `test` in the `main` function).

Arrays can not be reallocated. If you want to reallocate the memory you need to allocate the original memory dynamically as well.

Comment: I would like to write the same answer: You should dynamically allocate the initial array. Another option is to newly allocate, copy old contents and throw the old array away (without using `free()` because old array may not be freeable). I don't recommend this because this may cause memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

`newStaff.pic` is initialized to `NULL` and not updated then, so `realloc(newStaff.pic, (array[i].imagecount) * sizeof(int));` is equivalent to `malloc((array[i].imagecount) * sizeof(int));`.
Elements allocated via `malloc()` and not initialized hae indeterminate value, and they happened to be zero in this case.
You can take over the contents by manually copying them.

```
int *newpics = realloc(newStaff.pic, (array[i].imagecount) * sizeof(int));
/* add this line to copy contents */
for (int j = 0; j < array[i].imagecount-1; j++) newpics[j] = array[i].img[j];
newpics[array[i].imagecount-1] = newpic;
```

Unfortunately, this method is not good because this may cause memory leak if addition like this to the same element of `array` is done multiple times.
Better way is to allocate the buffer to assign to `img` dynamically and pass them to `realloc()`. Then, `realloc()` will do the copying for you.

Initialization part:

```
int test[3]  = {1,2,3};

Staff myStaff[5] = { {"Adam", test, 3},{"Anna",test,3} };

staffCount=2;

/* add this to change statically allocated arrays to dynamically allocated ones */
for (int i = 0; i < staffCOunt; i++) {
    int* newpics = malloc(myStaff[i].imagecount * sizeof(int));
    for (int j = 0; j < myStaff[i].imagecount; j++) newpics[j] = myStaff[i].img[j];
    myStaff[i].img = newpics;
}
```

Updating part:

```
/* use array[i].pic instead of newStaff.pic */
int *newpics = realloc(array[i].pic, (array[i].imagecount) * sizeof(int));
/* then, no manual copying is required */
```

(error checkings are omitted)